# Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; casued by No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Failed to start bean `eurekaAutoServiceRegistration` caused by No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class WebRun extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebRun.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebRun.class, args);
    }

    }
```

> 2-May-2019 16:45:22.965 信息 [http-nio-9999-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' 22-May-2019 16:46:04.846 严重
>   [http-nio-9999-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log
>   StandardWrapper.Throwable
>     org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name
>   'refresh'         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
>         at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1142)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name
>   'refresh'         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:705)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>         at
>   com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4652f076.getInfo()
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:55)
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37)
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:73)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
>         ... 30 more 22-May-2019 16:46:04.847 严重 [http-nio-9999-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate
>   exception for servlet [dispatcher]    java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'      at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:705)
>         at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>         at
>   com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4652f076.getInfo()
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:55)
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37)
>         at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:73)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
>         at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1142)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **a mistake in your project configuration** or a **version mismatching in your dependencies**.
**Case(1):**
Please check **you don't have more than one class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`**.
In one of the my projects, I had the two below classes by mistake:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CamponoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Therefore, I **deleted the second class** from the my project and the problem was solved.

I hope this helps you