# Deploy Eureka Client Failure On Tomcat - Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration': No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

Tags: tomcat, netflix-eureka

I am deploying a eureka client on external tomcat server. This problem is appearing when deploying the application:

> Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration': No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem with WebLogic, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Tarun what is your packaging? war or jar?If it is war, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619162/10976088